# How to connect two php codes

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, postgresql

This is my code to select the location from dropdown menu and to draw pie chart from the postgresql database. I am not able to draw pie chart on selecting the specific location instead on selecting a location pie chart is appearing which contains all the values of a columns.

Database to create pie chart :

[image]

> Code to select state Select.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fetch_select(val)
    { 
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'connect.php',
    data: {
    get_option:val
    },
    success: function (response) {
    document.getElementById("fd").innerHTML=response; 
    }
    });
    }

    </script>
    </body>
    <div id="select">
    <select onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
    <option>Select District</option>
    <?php


    $host = 'localhost';
    $port = '5433';
    $database = 'sustainable';
    $user = 'postgres';
    $password = 'postgis';

    $connectString = 'host=' . $host . ' port=' . $port . ' dbname=' . $database . 
    ' user=' . $user . ' password=' . $password;
    $link = pg_connect ($connectString);
    if (!$link)
    {
    die('Error: Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
    }
    $query='select id,location,sdg_4,sdg_5 from sustainable_development';
    $result = pg_query($query);


    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                  unset($id, $name);
                  $id = $row['id'];
                  $name = $row['location']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

    }

    echo "</select>";

    ?>
    <div id="fd">
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

> Code to draw pie chart
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Pie Chart Demo (LibChart)- https://codeofaninja.com/</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <br></br>

    <?php
    include "C:/xampp/htdocs/sdg/tools/libchart/libchart/classes/libchart.php";
    $chart = new PieChart( 500, 300 );
    $dataSet = new XYDataSet();
    $host = 'localhost';
    $port = '5433';
    $database = 'sustainable';
    $user = 'postgres';
    $password = 'postgis';
    $connectString = 'host=' . $host . ' port=' . $port . ' dbname=' . $database . ' user=' . $user . ' password=' . $password;
    $link = pg_connect ($connectString);
    if (!$link)
    {
    die('Error: Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
    }
    $query = 'select * from sustainable_development';
    $result = pg_query($query);
    $i=0;
    if($i < pg_num_fields($result))
    {
    while( $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result) ){
            extract($row);
            $dataSet->addPoint(new Point("{$sdg_4}", $sdg_4));
            $dataSet->addPoint(new Point("{$sdg_5}",$sdg_5));
            //break;
            }
        $chart->setDataSet($dataSet);
        $chart->setTitle("SDG score for SDG_4 and SDG_5");
        $chart->render("1.png");
        echo "<img alt='Pie chart'  src='1.png' style='border: 1px solid gray;'/>";

    }
    else{
        echo "No programming languages found in the database.";
    }
    pg_free_result($result);

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> Output displayed :

[image]

> Output required is :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you put that php code in a different file?

And then call it:

```
include('/my/phpfile.php')
```

Answer (score 3):

the require once code lets you connect code in different directory and in the same directory.
the dots stand for that it is in the same directory.
this is the code for the the other directory:

```
require_once("../includes/database.php");
```

this is the code for the same directory.

```
require_once("database.php");
```

i think this might be the anwser you are looking for and also the best and most organised way.
so i would recommend to put it in a different php file and link them using this code sample.

*NOTE* in my case the file is named database.php